# Add image attachment to existing document

Tags: python, image, http, flask, couchdb

I have a document with an image attachment. I'm looking to add another image to the document so that the document will hold multiple attachments i.e images, and images attachments that were previously in the existing will not be lost.

I am able to upload an image to an existing document but it deletes the image that was already there. I don't want this. I want to add in the new image and keep the old, I want to be able to have a document with multiple images. I know I have the rev_id hardcoded but its for testing.

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
if request.method == 'POST':

    memeName = request.form['memeName']
    memeBaseName = request.form['memeBaseName']
    file = request.form['data']

    if file:
        print("file: ", file)
        memeName += ".png"
        print("memeName: ", memeName)
        print("memeBaseName: ", memeBaseName)

        atachmentJson = {
            "_id": memeBaseName,
            "_rev": "5-60b616d491050e36302797eb126dcfa8",
            "_attachments":
                {
                    memeName:
                        {
                            "content_type": "image/png",
                            "data": file
                        }
                }
        }
        uploadRequest = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5984/' + database + '/', data=None, json=atachmentJson)

        print("uploadRequest: ", uploadRequest.status_code)

        if uploadRequest.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return jsonify({'name': "Meme Uploaded"})

        elif uploadRequest.status_code == requests.codes.created:
            return jsonify({'name': "Meme Uploaded"})

        elif uploadRequest.status_code == requests.codes.accepted:
            return jsonify({'name': "Meme Uploaded"})

        else:
            return jsonify({'error': "Failed to Upload Meme. Sorry :("})
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. Nowhere in your code are you adding an attachment to an existing document--you're just creating a new document. Can you paste the code that's actually causing you problems?

Comment: I thought that was the code to update an existing document, thats actually my code that Im working with. the only new bit that I added i , was the rev_id, I thought that would update the attachment instead of creating a new, but its creating a new one and I dont know how to just update. sorry for the confusion and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your code creates a document with `uploadRequest = requests.post(...)`, then it returns a result based on the status code. What part did you think was adding an attachment?

Comment: If you want to add an attachment to an existing document, you must use issue a PUT request to `/{db}/{docid}/{attname}` as documented [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/document/attachments.html#put--db-docid-attname).

Comment: the rev_id coupled with "_attachments": and the code that follows. would you be able to point me in the right direction please

Comment: That's just defining the document--with a single attachment. Then you create that document, with a random ID by posting to the database.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks very much, what do I have to do with the rev_id?

Comment: You must pass the `_rev` as a query parameter, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try that.

Comment: Hi @Flimzy, Sorry for coming back her again a month later! but I tried what you said, and still couldnt get it to work. I change from post to put and now I get a 412 error. Im still not sure how to do a query parameter, sorry would you be able to give me a hand again, please if you woudnt mind